# Arcgis 3D map development when display PictureMarkerSymbol in sceneview

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When I am displaying PictureMarkerSymbol it gives below exception in console.

```
> DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
> 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at "image url here"
> may not be loaded.(…) "Error: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
> 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at
> https://webapps-cdn.esri.com/Apps/MegaMenu/img/logo.jpg may not be
> loaded.
>     at Error (native)
>     at Object.makePotTexture (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:244:181)
>     at Object.texImage2D (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:241:437)
>     at b.loadGl (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:238:366)
>     at e.aquire (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:269:453)
>     at f.aquireIfNotUndefined (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:84:404)
>     at Object.f.singleTextureGLMaterialConstructor (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:86:1)
>     at new x (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:667:213)
>     at h.aquireExt (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:418:406)
>     at h.aquire (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:417:465)
>     ----------------------------------------
>     rejected at c (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:154:313)
>     at e (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:154:65)
>     at f (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:153:349)
>     at b.resolve (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:155:406)
>     at _loadedHandler (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1337:242)
>     at http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:793:83
>     at q.done (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:793:298)
>     at _doneLoadingCallback (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:789:529)
>     at z (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:798:307)
>     at HTMLImageElement.d.onload (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:790:332)
>     ---------------------------------------- Error
>     at then.c.then (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:156:177)
>     at https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:177:128
>     at _prepareImageResources (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1122:284)
>     at _prepareResources (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1119:301)
>     at constructor (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1133:34)
>     at new <anonymous> (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:45:148)
>     at Object.make (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1116:186)
>     at constructor (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1113:287)
>     at new <anonymous> (https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:45:148)
>     at e.getOrCreateGraphics3DSymbol (http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/views/SceneView.js:1069:390)"
```

Comment: can anyone know this issue and is it possible to add PictureMarkerSymbol  in 3d map using js 4.0

Comment: It seems a CROSS issues.

From the documentation:

"To avoid CORS issues with this symbol, do one of the following:
Use an image hosted on the same domain as the application.
If the image is on a different domain and that server is CORS enabled, add the domain to the corsEnabledServers array.
Install a proxy."

Comment: thnx for the answer, that is criss issue, now I used a local image, but it is not display in my 3D map, I have add the PictureMarkerSymbol as a symbol property in Graphic, but it only display as a point, not the image as follow API point. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=graphics-basic-3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your example using a PictureMarkerSymbol and it works.
The image and the html page are on the same webserver.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>3D Graphics - 4.0</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",

        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/geometry/Polyline",
        "esri/geometry/Polygon",

        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
      function(
        Map, SceneView, GraphicsLayer,
        Graphic, Point, Polyline, Polygon,
        PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol
      ) {

        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "hybrid"
        });

        var view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,

          camera: { // autocasts as new Camera()
            position: { // autocasts as new Point()
              x: -0.17746710975334712,
              y: 51.44543992422466,
              z: 1266.7049653716385
            },
            heading: 0.34445102566290225,
            tilt: 82.95536300536367
          }
        });

        /*********************
         * Add graphics layer
         *********************/

        var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.add(graphicsLayer);

        /*************************
         * Add a 3D point graphic
         *************************/

        // London
        var point = new Point({
            x: -0.178,
            y: 51.48791,
            z: 1010
          }),

          symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
            url: "http://yourserver/logo.jpg",
            width: "8px",
            height: "8px"
          });

        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: symbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);

        /****************************
         * Add a 3D polyline graphic
         ****************************/

        var polyline = new Polyline([
            [-0.178, 51.48791, 0],
            [-0.178, 51.48791, 1000]
          ]),

          lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol({
            color: [226, 119, 40],
            width: 4
          });

        var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: polyline,
          symbol: lineSymbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);

        /***************************
         * Add a 3D polygon graphic
         ***************************/

        var polygon = new Polygon([
            [-0.184, 51.48391, 400],
            [-0.184, 51.49091, 500],
            [-0.172, 51.49091, 500],
            [-0.172, 51.48391, 400],
            [-0.184, 51.48391, 400]
          ]),

          fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol({
            color: [227, 139, 79, 0.8],
            outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
              color: [255, 255, 255],
              width: 1
            }
          });

        var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: polygon,
          symbol: fillSymbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(polygonGraphic);

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Point symbols and labels do not appear in the scene in browser chrome, please refer the the url for more details "https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/troubleshoot.htm#anchor47"

Answer (score 1):

@lele3p is correct.  the best option here is to host the image on the same domain as the application.

you can information about CORS and using a proxy as a failsafe in instances where it is either not possible to enable CORS on the web server hosting resources or in legacy browsers like IE9 and < here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html